# WKWebView not playing next video in background

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView()` that plays embedded YouTube videos. I'm passing in an array of video IDs to the YouTube JS API and displaying videos in the web view. In the foreground, videos play automatically, one after the other.

When my app enters the background, the video resumes playing (thanks to `evaluateJavaScriptWithString()`). However, based on whether I enter the background by clicking the home button or the sleep/wake (lock) button, the `WKWebView()` will do one of two things when the next video loads:

If I press the sleep/wake (lock) button, the videos will continue playing consecutively even in the background, as it should. Granted, I always get this notification:

```
2015-12-16 01:34:26.793 App[10335:1967149]  ** -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x13c36f240> {
    handler = remote;
    info = <BSSettings: 0x13c36b0f0> {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}
```

...but the videos keep on playing. **Now, when I press the home button, the following video will not play.** It will stop at the end of the currently played video and not play the next video, even if I call a custom `play()` function on the web view.

I have Javascript code for the YouTube iFrame that lets me control the player. When the player state changes (when a video ends), the following code is called. I'm wondering if `window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage()` has anything to do with it.

```
var index = 0

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

   if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED) { 

        var message = "next video index:"+index   

        try {

             console.log('Video has ended'); 
             window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(message);

        } catch(err) {

             console.log('The native context does not exist yet');

        }
   }
}
```

My question is: iOS is clearly able to load the next videos in the background as shown by the sleep/wake (lock) button. It does so without fail. Why isn't this the case after entering the background via the home button? It's the same background mode.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?